# Is there a way to move icons to edge of a screen

Tags: icons, xfce

I have an unusual question. Is there a way to move the icon to the edge of the screen across the entire width of the desktop, and obviously keep they aligned as they were. I mean that icon grid would be extended on the whole desktop avoid leaving free space at the edges of the screen. Maybe it is not "high-priority" problem but still annoying for me. I'm using xubuntu with xfce desktop environment but I'm pretty sure there is the same problem on ubuntu's unity.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I am wrong, but just try this:

1. Right click on the desktop icons
2. You will find some choices regarding to icon alignment.
3. Do this for each icon, I am afraid.

Moreover, I found this page will be suitable for solving this problem.

http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-customize-your-ubuntu-desktop--cms-21316